# Laravel exporting multiple items from object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm tryign to export multiple items from an object to a CSV in Laravel 5.1 using the `Laravel Excel` [package](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs) by maatwebsite.

The code I am using works but only exports the last record and not all records.

The code I have is:

```
return Excel::create('Voucher-Export-'.time(), function($excel) use($rows)
{
    $excel->setTitle('Voucher Export');
    $excel->sheet('Voucher Export', function($sheet) use($rows) {
        foreach($rows->items() as $row) {
            $sheet->fromArray($row->toArray());
        }
    });
})->store('xls', false, true);
```

`$rows` holds an object like this:

```
array:20 [▼
  0 => Coupon {#369 ▼
    #table: "coupons"
    #fillable: array:8 [▶]
    #connection: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #perPage: 15
    +incrementing: true
    +timestamps: true
    #attributes: array:12 [▶]
    #original: array:12 [▶]
    #relations: []
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #appends: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #casts: []
    #touches: []
    #observables: []
    #with: []
    #morphClass: null
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  }
  1 => Coupon {#370 ▶}
  2 => Coupon {#371 ▶}
  3 => Coupon {#372 ▶}
  4 => Coupon {#373 ▶}
  5 => Coupon {#374 ▶}
  6 => Coupon {#375 ▶}
  7 => Coupon {#376 ▶}
  8 => Coupon {#377 ▶}
  9 => Coupon {#378 ▶}
  10 => Coupon {#379 ▶}
  11 => Coupon {#380 ▶}
  12 => Coupon {#381 ▶}
  13 => Coupon {#382 ▶}
  14 => Coupon {#383 ▶}
  15 => Coupon {#384 ▶}
  16 => Coupon {#385 ▶}
  17 => Coupon {#386 ▶}
  18 => Coupon {#387 ▶}
  19 => Coupon {#388 ▶}
]
```

However, this results in only the last row being exported.  Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: If `$rows` is an array, surely your code should be `foreach ($rows as $row)` not `foreach ($rows->items() as $rows)`. However, if, as I assume, you've simplified this case and your `rows` variable is actually a model and`->items()` is some kind of a relationship method - try calling it without the `()` - `foreach ($user->addresses as $address)` rather than `foreach ($user->addresses() as $address)`. I'm not saying this will definitely fix your issue - getting only the last item is odd - but maybe it'll help you look at your code with a bit more scrutiny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't worked with this plugin, but from the [docs](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export#array) it looks like you are passing in a row array and not an array of row arrays.

I imagine your code is failing because `$sheet->fromArray()` creates a sheet and not a row, so only the last `$row` is loaded as a sheet.

**docs example**

```
Excel::create('Filename', function($excel) {
  $excel->sheet('Sheetname', function($sheet) {
    $sheet->fromArray(array(
      array('data1', 'data2'),
      array('data3', 'data4')
    ));
  });
})->export('xls');
```

**your new code**

```
return Excel::create('Voucher-Export-'.time(), function($excel) use($rows)
{
  $excel->setTitle('Voucher Export');
  $excel->sheet('Voucher Export', function($sheet) use($rows) {
    $sheet->fromArray($rows->toArray());
  });
})->store('xls', false, true);
```